Should I use well-known labels as selectors for services and deployments?
According to the well-known label docs (app.kubernetes.io/name, app.kubernetes.io/component, ...)

In order to take full advantage of using these labels, they should be applied on every resource object.

however I rarely see any in real life. I admit, I don't see a lot of other Kubernetes projects, but I'd expect them everywhere in Helm Charts and examples in blog posts. And also the official docs on selectors do not use them, mention or link them.
Follow up question: If I really specify all of these 6 recommended labels there's a lot of redundancy, I'd use the same name and component for the deployment, the pods in its template as well as the service for the deployment pods. Any downsides to that except a lot of DRY?
Self-answered querstion: Am I overthinking this? Yes, definitely, but maybe there're some aspects I didn't think of, yet.
